# How to return a record for every item in the 'where value in ' clause?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

**Oracle11g**

I want to know if a player has ever played shortstop. However, a player
may not even be in my table, yet I'd still like to return a row for that player. In this case, player #3 is not in table, but I'd like to return a row nevertheless.

**Selection Criteria**

> If player has at least one SHORTSTOP record then return just 1 row with YES.
>
> If player has at least one record and none of them are SHORTSTOP then return just one row with NO.
>
> If player has no records then return just one row with NO.

**Query**

```
with baseball_players as 
(select 1 as player_id, 'SHORTSTOP' as position  from dual union all
 select 1 as player_id, 'FIRSTBASE' as position  from dual union all
 select 2 as player_id, 'FIRSTBASE' as position  from dual)                                                  
select player_id,  case position 
   when 'SHORTSTOP' then 'YES' 
   else 'NO'
   end   has_played
from baseball_players 
where player_id in (1,2,3)
```

**Question:** How can I write query to get desired results?

**Desired Output**

```
PLAYER_ID  HAS_PLAYED
----------------------
   1        YES
   2        NO
   3        NO
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I just added question to OP..

Comment: How are you going to pass the `player_id` to the query? Can you please post the structure of **your** table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
WITH playerList AS
    (
        SELECT 
            1 player_id
        FROM 
            dual
        UNION
        SELECT 
            2
        FROM 
            dual
        UNION
        SELECT 
            3
        FROM 
            dual
    )
, baseball_players as 
    (
        select 1 as player_id, 'SHORTSTOP' as position  from dual union all
        select 1 as player_id, 'FIRSTBASE' as position  from dual union all
        select 2 as player_id, 'FIRSTBASE' as position  from dual 
    )
SELECT 
    pl.player_id
    , MAX(CASE WHEN bp.position = 'SHORTSTOP' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END)
FROM
    playerList pl
LEFT JOIN 
    baseball_players bp
    ON 
    bp.player_id = pl.player_id
GROUP BY 
    pl.player_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a where clause, create a tempoary table, insert the values in and left join on the table you created.

Use a case statement for IF NULL then NO, otherwise YES.